# Playsound python module can't find file even in same folder

Tags: python

I have imported the playsound python module and put a mp3 file in the same folder as the python file, and yet when I run the file all I get is an error message saying

```
        open Sound.mp3
    Cannot find the specified file.  Make sure the path and filename are correct.

    Error 263 for command:
        close Sound.mp3
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
Failed to close the file: Sound.mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

File lookup is usually relative to the current working directory and not the Python source file itself. You could either run the script from the directory with the sound file (`cd /path/to/sound_files`, `python3 /path_to_script`), or pass and absolute path to the sound file when calling `playsound`.

If you're using an IDE, the working directory can usually be set in the run configuration.